# Can a two variable parametric equation ever determine a 3-D surface?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to concoct a set of two-variable parametric equations (let us say just three equations for simplicity) that determines a 3-dimensional surface / a solid geometric object in $\mathbb{R}$$^3$? I suppose the $2$-dimensional analog to this question would be, could we find two equations $x$ $=$ $f(t)$ and $y$ $=$ $g(t)$ where
$t$ $\in$ $I$ for some subset $I$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$, such that the set { ($f(t)$, $g(t)$) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$$^2$  $|$ $t$ $\in$ $I$ } is a 2-dimensional surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a function with 1D domain is enough: there are [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), continuous functions
$$f:[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n$$
with n-dimensional image set.

**But** the space-filling curves are very bad behaved: not differentiable and not injective.